# Plotting multiple markers in Google Maps

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

Hi I am working on Google Maps SDK for ios. I want to plot a number of markers in Google maps from NSArray which contains location name, latitude and longitude.
I tried using For loops which seems a little lame already but,

```
 for(int i=0;i<=[myArray count];i++){
    self.view = mapView_;
    NSString *lat = [[myArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"latitude"];
    NSString *lon = [[myArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"longitude"];
    double lt=[lat doubleValue];
    double ln=[lon doubleValue];        
    NSString *name = [[myArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSLog(@"%@ and %@ and %f and %f of %@",lat,lon, lt,ln,name);
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.animated=YES;
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lt,ln);
    marker.title = name;
    marker.snippet = @"Kathmandu";
    marker.map = mapView_;
```

}

Here **myarray** is the array that has location name , latitude longitude in string format which I converted it to double. When I run this code Xcode shows me NSRangeException: index beyond bounds, which is probably because I am trying to use same object to display different indexes in same map. But at the same time, I couldnot think of any way to use **GMSMarker** as array. 
I could however plot multiple markers if I used different GMSMarker objects, but that doesnot solve my problem. I made another object like this, using two GMSMarker objects work to show two markers on the same map.

```
 GMSMarker *marker1 = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
 marker1.animated=YES;
 marker1.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lt,ln);
 marker1.title = name;
 marker1.snippet = @"Kathmandu";
 marker1.map = mapView_;
```

Any help?

Comment: I don' exactly understand the problem. this for loop crashes with an index out of range exception? what's this command's output? `NSLog(@"%@ and %@ and %f and %f of %@",lat,lon, lt,ln,name);` it prints you out all the documents from your array?

Comment: and also please explain what you mean by saying "you used different GSMMarker objects"

Comment: I used the NSLog to make sure all the elements have valid elements and to check the for loop. the for loop executes only once and the NSRangeException occurs showing index beyond bounds in reason. I will edit in my code about GMSMarker object.

Comment: sounds like your array is malformed. do this: `NSDictionary *d = [myArray objectAtIndex:i]` before the `NSString *lat =` and put a breakpoint to check where exactly it crashes. Also try to remove the marker code and leave only the loop to run alone. It could be very helpful if you paste the part you generate the `myArray` data.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. The problem was the myarray count. i should have done i<[myArray count] instead of i<=[myArray count],

Comment: One last stupid question.. what do I do with this post now? I mean i found out the problem.. Can i close it or something?

Comment: nothing to do with that. if you believe that my answer helped you out mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

> But at the same time, I couldnot think of any way to use GMSMarker as array.

try this:

```
NSMutableArray *markersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i=0;i<[myArray count];i++){

    // ... initialise marker here
    marker.map = mapView_;

    [markersArray addObject:marker];
    [marker release];
}
```

Comment: But I need to use Google Maps.

Comment: I updated my answer. This way you keep all the references of your Marker objects in an array.